# When do I have to use 做/当 instead of 是?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage

I know 做/当 in some contexts may mean "to be", as in:

> - 他现在**做**老师了。 He **is** a teacher now.
> - 她愿意**做**我女朋友。 She accepted **to be** my girlfriend.
> - 我毕业后想**做**经理。 After I graduate I want **to be** a manager.

I have a hard time explaining to my students when they have to use 做/当 and can't use 是. Any ideas?

Comment: 願意/想 (*want to*) should be used with 做/當 (*become*). Note that there isn't anything particularly wrong with saying "他現在是老師了", and you can also say something like "她現在是我女朋友".

Comment: 作 may be used instead of 做: bkrs：作，（充当; 担任） act as; be; become:
我来作翻译。 I'll act as interpreter.
人民当家作主人。 The people are the masters of their country

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, 是 expresses a **state** 一种状态 and it's used to state a **fact**，while 做/当 denotes an **act** 一种动作, meaning 充当，担任.  For example, 我是老师 clarified the fact you are a teacher, while 我做/当老师 denotes you want to act as a teacher even if sometimes it's not really your job.