# Why do we use 做 in 我太喜欢和他做朋友了 as "being"?

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Sentence:

> 我太喜欢和他做朋友了

How can we use 做 in this meaning in other sentences?
Where can I read more about it and what is the name of this "rule"?

And what is the meaning of the 了 in this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

做 + identity = be identity

Example:做好人，做首領 (good person and leader are identities)

做 + procedure/action = do procedure

Example: 做大事， 做錯，做工 (great thing, mistake and work involve procedures or action)

the final particle 了 is a modal word for emphasis, if you remove it, the meaning of the sentence would not change, but the tone would be flat

Example sentence:

"要(做)大人物就要(做)大事" = "to (be) a great man, you need to (do) great thing"

> *Why do we use 做 in this sentence as “being”?*

朋友 is an identity

Answer (score 1):

Well, whereas in English you 'be a friend,' in Chinese you '做朋友。‘ Not much of a rule. Why does that surprise you? Do you think Chinese must copy English?

Have a look [here](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/505A.htm). Number 8

我太喜欢和他做朋友了。

You could write:
我太喜欢当他的朋友。

Edit: I was reading an interview with a TV presenter today. He was asked if he acts role of an intellectual in his TV show. He said:

“我只是在做我自己”

I think there may be a *similar* form in English.

A: You should try to be more friendly.
B: I don't do friendly!

What is the meaning of 了? That is a whole Pandora's Box of questions!

The simplest answer is, it makes the sentence sound complete. Otherwise it sounds strange, according to a Chinese friend.

Answer (score 0):

> *Original*: 我太喜欢和他做朋友了
> I much like with him being friends

***1. 太...了***

First, it uses the 太...了 grammar construct: see [Expressing "excessively" with "tai"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22excessively%22_with_%22tai%22).  Most learners encounter this almost immediately with 太贵了.  Here, it's used for emphasis, such as in 你太好了 or

> 我**太**喜欢吃饺子**了**
> I much like to eat dumplings

To simplify breaking it down further, I'll delete the 太 and 了, which only reduces the emphasis.  I.e.:

> 我喜欢和他做朋友
> I like with him being friends

***2. What if we delete the 做?***

We get a sentence which is incomplete:

> 我喜欢和他朋友  ✗
> I like with his friend [..?]

Here, 他朋友 is interpreted as "his friend", i.e., 他的朋友; see [Expressing close possession without "de"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_close_possession_without_%22de%22).

***3. Why 做 and not something else?***

[做](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%81%9A) is one of these Chinese words that have a lot of meanings.  In the original sentence, it could mean any of these (or some combination, or something in between):

> to do; to make; to act as; to be; to become; to function (in some capacity); to serve as; to form (a bond or relationship)

Precisely what it means depends on context, which is presumably known to the people speaking.

In principle, in sentences like these, it's possible to replace 做 with 当:

> 我太喜欢和他[**当**](http://www.youdao.com/w/%E5%BD%93)朋友了

But in this example, it seems the formal and distanced 当 is mismatched with the informal and positive 太喜欢...了.  This is probably not true all the time, but it's my impression.  Compare it with examples such as the following:

> 我说过和他**当朋友**，他还是会说些逾越友情的话<sup>[[src]](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/436766394328214004.html)</sup>
> I said I was friends with him, [but] he still says a few exceeding-friendship words
>
> 怎样让一个男生知道，我只是想和他**当朋友**...<sup>[[src]](https://www.zhihu.com/question/36331887?sort=created)</sup>
> How can I let a man know, I only want to be friends...

(For why it's not 是, see [When do I have to use 做/当 instead of 是?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/29375/when-do-i-have-to-use-%e5%81%9a-%e5%bd%93-instead-of-%e6%98%af))

***4. Other examples***

> How can we use 做 in this meaning in other sentences?

Here's some examples I found searching the web:

> 我立志**做**一名老师<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1618516714301451809&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup>
> I'm determined **to be** a good teacher
>
> **做**妈妈后,为什么大家都失去了自我?<sup>[[src]](http://www.sohu.com/a/127576918_580337)</sup>
> After **becoming** a mother, why [does] everyone lose their self
>
> 我想**做**小偷<sup>[[src]](http://zuowen.360zuowen.com/xiaoxuexieshi/00182424.html)</sup>
> I want **to be** a thief
>
> 谁想**做**百万富翁？<sup>[[src]](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%B0%81%E6%83%B3%E5%81%9A%E7%99%BE%E4%B8%87%E5%AF%8C%E7%BF%81/1140517?fr=aladdin)</sup>
> Who wants **to be** a millionaire?

Answer (score 0):

Quote：- “In principle, in sentences like these, it's possible to replace 做 with 当"

Interesting, because if you combine the two to 当做, it becomes "to treat, to regard, to perceive, to look upon" someone *as a friend* and not *making someone a friend* as 做 by itself would.

You can also replace 做 with 交, (jiao) which is, I think, less colloquial.